# Sill pan for window - drawbacks of creating positive slope by angling sill 2x4

Tags: framing, windows, waterproofing, flashing

At 0:38 of this FineHomeBuilding video https://youtu.be/zEleTgfifS0?t=38, it says one valid way to create a positive slope for making a sill pan for a window is to angle the rough sill by 5 degrees to the outside.  I'm considering going this route due to SureSill not being in stock nor beveled cedar.  Are there any drawbacks to taking this approach that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angling the rough sill is perfectly ok. That was the old school way before fancy presills and suresill.